# MySQL inner join, limit for each category

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables: `x_products` and `x_category`

I have to select the last 3 products inserted (order by `x_products.data` column, descending) for each category using a single query.

My idea was to use an `INNER JOIN` technique (for using a single query).

I've tried to use `LIMIT 0,3`, but only the last 3 products are returned (3 per total, but not for each category.

```
SELECT products.* 
FROM x_products products
INNER JOIN x_category categories
ON products.category = categories.id
ORDER BY products.data DESC LIMIT 0,3
```

How could I select 3 products for each category, but not 3 products per total?

Comment: Look at the `GROUP BY` statement

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results\

Comment: Still struggling? If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might help,

```
SELECT products.* 
FROM x_products products
INNER JOIN x_category categories
ON products.category = categories.id
GROUP BY products.category
ORDER BY products.data DESC LIMIT 0,3
```

And yeah you can find a few examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)